# Particle emmiters not even over mirrored mesh

Tags: modeling, particles

I have a simple mesh of a wall, I'm trying to add a particle system in order to cell fracture the mesh but the emitters are clumping together in certain sections.

The two areas either side of the main gate area are a mirror so the geometry is identical but it appears to favour the right over the left.

Any idea how I can get a random yet even distribution over the whole mesh regardless of faces/verts etc?

I've tried using random and jitter, also volumetric over faces but ideally I want them all on the surface of the mesh, any ideas would be awesome[image]

Settings are default except for start and end frame which are both set to 1[image][image]

Comment: Please update your question with additional details regarding your mesh (you could include a screenshot in wireframe or edit mode) and your particle settings.

Comment: Apologies, details have been added along with pictures, hopefully they prove helpful

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Could it be that there is duplicated geometry in the right side? In Edit mode, select all, press 'M' and merge 'by distance', increasing the distance slightly to remove any 'close' vertices. That's the only reason I can think that there would be more particles on one side than the other.

Comment: Not at all, you were right it needed a little more info :) After the mirror modifier to create both sides of the wall i actually used a merge by distance to clean up some duplicated vertices in the centre. I've checked and can't see any duplicate or internal geometry :/

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution....

For some reason the "Even Distribution" check box was doing the exact opposite, once I unchecked it, it had the desired effect.

Thank you for your help Rich Sedman!